# Почему первый элемнт шапки находится чуть ниже остальных элементов?

Tags: html, css

Изучаю css, столкнулась со странной проблемой, первый элемент шапки, чуть ниже чем остальные элементы шапки, как можно это исправить?

```css
/* Шапка */
.header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    background: rosybrown;

}

.header_container{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 104px; /* размер шапки */
    align-items: center;
}

.header_logo{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: inherit;

}

.header_menu{
    margin: 0 0 0 133px;
}

.menu_list{
    display: flex;
background-color: aqua;

}

.menu_item{
    align-items: center;
}
.menu_item:not(:last-child){
    margin: 0 21px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=devise-width,initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Макет</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">

        <div class="header_container container">

             <a href="" class="header_logo">
                 Relvise
                 <nav class="header_menu menu">
                     <ul class="menu_list">



                         <li class="menu_item">
                             <a href="" class="menu_link">Contact</a>
                         </li>

                     <li class="menu_item">
                         <a href="" class="menu_link">Home</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="menu_item">
                         <a href="" class="menu_link">Product</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="menu_item">
                         <a href="" class="menu_link">Pricing</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="menu_item">
                         <a href="" class="menu_link">Contact</a>
                     </li>


                     </ul>

                 </nav>
             </a>
        </div>
    </header>

</div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если посмотреть в инспекторе то у первого элемента появляется такой `<a href="" class="header_logo"></a>` дочерний элемент, если удалить его то ошибка пропадёт

Comment: спасибо большое разобралась.